# Como validar usuario y contraseña en MVC

Tags: c#, xml, mvc, login

Tengo una aplicacion que usa MVC donde tengo una pagina de autenticacion la cual requiero que valide un usuario y contraseña.

Tengo el algoritmo de encripcion para poder guardar la contraseña en un archivo xml lo cual esta serializado en la aplicacion.

Lo que requiero es poder validar esto cuando el usuario va a conectarse. No se como hacerlo.

Como puedo validar la contraseña y usuario para poder autorizar la conexion?

Este es mi codigo de autenticacion, cuando el usuario pondra su contraseña y numero de usuario:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(ModelLogin model)
    {
        copyConfigViewModelLogin = model;

        SerializeDeserializeXml<ModelLogin>.Serialize(GlobalVariables.pathLoginXml, model);


        return RedirectToAction("Index", model);
    }
```

Como veran la variable pathLoginXml es la que contiene el archivo xml lo cual contiene el usuario y contraseña

Cuando el usuario hace click in Login desde una pagina cshtml, la linea return `RedirectToAction("Index", model);` me manda hacia otra pagina llamada index lo cual es lo que quiero.

Busco poder validar esto antes de mandar al usuario a esta pagina de index.

Este es el codigo el cual es la clase que uso para poder crear las variables de usuario y contraseña:

```
[Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [Display(Name = "User ID")]
        public string UserID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
        [DataType(DataType.Url)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
```

Se que requiero hacer esta validacion en el metodo `public ActionResult Login(ModelLogin model)` pero no se como hacerlo.

Gracias